# Updating SharePoint Online user profile photo using Powershell

Tags: user-profile, delve, exchange-online, spprofilephotostore

In O365, i understand that SP Online user profile photo and Delve photos gets synced from Exchange Online.

Is there any way I can directly update SharePoint Online user profile photo and delve photo using Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of adding your photo to Microsoft 365 via PowerShell is using the [Set-UserPhoto cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-userphoto?view=exchange-ps). This is clarified by Microsoft at the end of this article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-your-profile-photo-to-microsoft-365-2eaf93fd-b3f1-43b9-9cdc-bdcd548435b7

Adding photos using this method should ensure that the user's photo appears in other Microsoft 365 applications such as SharePoint and Delve.